# Should we make an IRC channel of this site?

Tags: feature-request

As title says, should we make an IRC channel for this site, like #askubuntu , or what?

Comment: Why would we want this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

Comment: Right, because that's what http://chat.askubuntu.com is for!

Comment: I was about to pounce on this... too bad I got here too late :)